# How to Cancel item level InProgress Workflow in SharePoint 2016 using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, development, powershell, csom

I want to cancel the In progress item level workflows in sharepoint 2016 using client side code in Powershell Or C# console app.

Searched most of the links , But nothing is working.
[programmatically-cancel-a-sharepoint-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048981/programmatically-cancel-a-sharepoint-workflow)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 workflow and SharePoint 2010 workflows are different, so you have to use different ways to cancel it.

This article would help you:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31910.sharepoint-cancelling-or-terminating-workflows-using-c-and-csom.aspx